# VS2008 project settings

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have updated project settings for sub-projects in VS2008 and projects build without errors. But, when I copy the updated project from one machine to the other all the updated project settings are lost. Because of this I'm not able to build the project on other machines without again updating the settings.

How can I make sure that all updated project settings are retained while copying from one PC to the other?

What are the files that are updated when any changes are done to project settings for sub-projects in VS2008?

Are the VC6 dsw, dsp files updated as well?
In-order to retain the updated project settings while copying the project to source control system, what files have to be copied?
Can we make a copy of all the updated settings as a vsprops file and inherit it to retain the updated changes?

Answer (score 1):

- .sln Files store the whole workspace settings
- .vcproj (for C++) or .csproj (for C#) store the actual project settings
- .user files store some specific user settings (e.g. debug settings set in the "Debugging" section of the project settings; However these files probably shouldn't be set under version control as VS2008 creates these files using Windows login name

VS2008 does not modify any dsw or dsp files after sln and vcproj files have been created

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Does it mean putting .sln and .vcproj files under version control retains the user specific project settings? Can the project be still built with the user specific settings on any other machine?

Comment: You forgot the .vsprops files for the project property sheets.

Comment: do u mean .vsprops file als ohas to be put under version control along with .sln and .vcproj?

Comment: it's just .vcproj that needs to be copied to retain updated settings